# Log4j Does not Send Mail unless Thread.sleep

Tags: java, log4j

I am having a problem with `log4j` and sending notification emails.

My log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.MAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.MAIL.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.MAIL.BufferSize=512
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPHost=10.10.10.10
log4j.appender.MAIL.From=team@domain.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.Subject=Subject Here
log4j.appender.MAIL.To=team@domain.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

The program caused an error when trying to send and email so I made a `log.error()` to test it.

I tested the code below, but it still did not send emails.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    log.error("Error ");
}
```

When I add a `Thread.sleep` in above code. It works!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    log.error("Error ");
    Thread.sleep(1000000L);
}
```

The problem is that `main thread` exits and so causes `mail sending thread` to terminate. So I decided to change the program to wait(not exit) until log4j sending mails completely. But I have no idea about how to get mail-sending status in log4j.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set BufferSize value to 1, maybe logger just waiting a full buffer before sending

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to

```
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown();
```

at the end of `main` method